# Change StandardController into Sobject list

Tags: apex, standardcontroller

Original code:

```
 public Total(ApexPages.StandardController standardController){
try{
    Id AccountId = standardController.getId();
    
   ///}
```

to

```
public Total(List<PAX__c> paxList){
    try{
        Id AccountId = paxList.getId();
///}
```

But the getId() on sobject doesnt work.
How should I do it?

Comment: `Id AccountId = paxList[0].get('Id');` For bulk you need to loop through the List (paxList)

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You must use an ApexPages.StandardController in order for the page to be used as a Visualforce extension controller. That said, you can immediately convert to a list afterwards:

```
public Total(ApexPages.StandardController standardController){
  List<PAX__c> paxList = new List<PAX__c> { (PAX__c)standardController.getRecord() };
```

---

Edit based on comment:

You can make a Visualforce page that provides a list of records using `ApexPages.StandardSetController`, as follows:

```
public class Total {
  public Total(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
    PAX__c[] records = (PAX__c[])controller.getRecords();
    // Do stuff here
  }
}
```

This requires changing the Visualforce page to include a `recordSetVar` (you need not use it, but it must be present):

```
<apex:page standardController="PAX__c" recordSetVar="records" extensions="Total">
```

Comment: Is there a way to generate a visualforce page to all accounts other than manually then?

Comment: @Amozino Ah, you want `ApexPages.StandardSetController`, and the VF page needs to have `recordVar` assigned as well. `<apex:page standardController="PAX__c" recordSetVar="records" extensions="Total">` and `public Total(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller){` And from there, you can use `controllergetRecords()`.

Comment: The thing is I already have a visualforce page that can modify a record.
I need to modify every account on that individual scale ( make them launch the visualforce page each)

Comment: I originally wanted to change the StandardController to a sobject list in order to mass update my records. ( with the Execute Anonymous Windows/ Data batch)

Comment: @Amozino You could change to (or add) a StandardSetController option and then read the records from there from your batch. Or something else. But you'd need to get the individual id from each record, as the original comment stated.